# Installing JavaFX 15 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx, javafx-11

I'm trying to install JavaFX 15 on my Mac but I'm stuck.

Running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

I've already installed Java 13 JDK and set the Home folder, downloaded the JavaFX SDK from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ , I've already ran the code "export PATH_TO_FX=/Users/.../javafx-sdk-15/lib" in Mac terminal.

I'm using IntelliJ for programming and I tried to set the path at Project Structure - Libraries

but apps won't compile.

Could somebody help me? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Note that the latest release of JavaFX is version _14_, which was released within the last month. JavaFX 15 is currently early-access (and will be for the next 5-6 months).

Answer (score 10):

<strike>the second command that DomQ posted was incorrect:</strike>

`brew tap bell-sw/liberica`

`brew install --cask liberica-jdk15-full`

Comment: Indeed! I fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

My experience is that [homebrew-liberica](https://github.com/bell-sw/homebrew-liberica) just works:

```
brew tap bell-sw/liberica
brew install --cask liberica-jdk15-full
```

Comment: On Homebrew 3.2.8, I had to use: brew install --cask liberica-jdk8-full

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the terminal or set up a launch configuration in VS Code.

To use the terminal, you can either install [Liberica](https://github.com/bell-sw/homebrew-liberica) or download [the latest JavaFX](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) from Gluon (or the *Early-Access build*). To compile your `*.java` file, make sure to specify and set the `--module-path` and the `-cp` as command arguments for `javac` on the CLI.

For [example](https://github.com/mavaddat-javid-education/java-debugging-kevinkaiyenmou/blob/master/Chapter15/JavaFXThing.java), if you downloaded the JavaFX SDK to your `~/Downloads` directory (i.e., you downloaded JavaFX 20 and extracted it in your ordinary **Downloads** folder), then you will run something like

```bash
javac --module-path "$(eval echo ~$USER)/Downloads/javafx-sdk-20/lib/*" -cp "$(eval echo ~$USER)/Downloads/javafx-sdk-20/lib/*" -d . JavaFXThing.java
```

Then, in order to run your program, you'll use:

```bash
java --module-path "$(eval echo ~$USER)/Downloads/javafx-sdk-20/lib"  --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml JavaFXThing
```

Check what modules you need to specify for the `--add-modules` parameter here: [API documentation for JavaFX 20](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/)

Here is a sample `launch.json` to enable debug launching in VS Code:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch JavaFX Class",
            "request": "launch",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"/Users/kevinmou/Downloads/javafx-sdk-20/lib\"  --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

For JDK, I recommend using [Liberica](https://github.com/bell-sw/homebrew-liberica) with a package manager such as [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), since it is easy to keep up-to-date and Liberica takes care of the paths and environment variables (including JavaFX).

### Package Managers for Liberica

#### SDKMAN! [image: SDKMAN! logo]

To install Liberica JDK using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), run:

```
sdk install java 17-librca
```

#### Homebrew [image: Homebrew logo]

To install Liberica JDK using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), run:

```
brew tap bell-sw/liberica
brew install --cask liberica-jdk17
```

Then, to update

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Please refer to [bell-sw/homebrew-liberica](https://github.com/bell-sw/homebrew-liberica) for
list of available packages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care with environment variables mixing with GUI applications on macOS.  Setting PATH_TO_FX in the terminal likely didn't set the value for the IntelliJ IDE.  You will note that the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij explicitly mention setting that value within the IDE, not from the Terminal.

I strongly suggest using Gradle or Maven with the code samples given at https://OpenJFX.io/ as a starting point.  Confirm that the builds work from the command line before debugging what the IDE might be doing differently.

You can also install a JDK that includes the JavaFX modules.  A few OpenJDK providers have such builds. For example:

- BellSoft produces a "Full JDK" Liberica JDK install,
  https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/
- Azul produces a "JDK FX" java package for
  Zulu builds of OpenJDK, https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/